# Porque no me sale un cupón de descuento con pizzas condicionales en Javascript

Tags: javascript, condiciones

**Los cupones no da descuento… los precios mismos. ¿Como calcular precios de pizza con cupon descuento?**

**Variables**

```
Tamaños Pizzas
var precioPizzaC = 100;//Chico
var precioPizzaM = 150;//Mediano
var precioPizzaG = 180;//Grande

// Cupones
var cupon0 = 0;//Cupon
var cupon10 = 10;//Cupon 10 %
var cupon20 = 20;//Cupon 20 %
```

**Condicionales**

```
if(cupon0 == cupon10){
    precioFinal = precioPchi - precioPchi * 0.10;
}else if (cupon0 == cupon20){
    precioFinal = precioPmed - precioPmed * 0.20;
}else{
    precioFinal = precioPizzaG;
}
console.log(precioPizzaC); //respuesta
```

Comment: la condición nunca se cumple por que los cupones tienen distintos precios. `cupon0` no tiene el mismo valor que `cupon10` \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: Tienes una lista de precios y otra de distintos cupones pero no aparece en el código cual es el cupón y el tamaño de la pizza seleccionados por el cliente. En los cupones también podrías almacenar directamente el factor de reducción (0.10, 0.20) en lugar de esos números (10, 20) que no empleas en el cálculo. El precioFinal siempre será igual a precioPizzaSeleccionada - (precioPizzaSeleccionada * factorReduccionSeleccionado) sin tantos if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu codigo esta bien, solo que `cupon0` siempre se queda en cero. Si le asignas el valor de otro cupon, el condicional correspondiente dara `true`.

Aca algo rapido:

```
//Tamaños Pizzas
var precioPizzaC = 100; //Chico
var precioPizzaM = 150; //Mediano
var precioPizzaG = 180; //Grande

// Cupones
var cupon0 = 0; //Cupon
var cupon10 = 10; //Cupon 10 %
var cupon20 = 20; //Cupon 20 %

cupon0 = cupon20; /* Le asignas el cupon de 10%. */
if (cupon0) 
    console.log(`El cupon es de ${cupon0}.`);
else 
    console.log("El cupon parece ser 0.");

console.log(precioPizzaC); //respuesta
```

### Resultado:

```
El cupon es de 20.
100
```

Fijate que debes asignarle a `cupon0` un valor.

---

En respuesta a:

> Esta no es mi respuesta... ¿Como calcular precios de pizza con cupon descuento? – HaziiProWD94

```
/* Crea un hash con las pizzas, y su respectivos costos y descuentos. */
let pizzas = {
    "Pequena": [
        100, .05    /* Para la pequena, costo de 100, 5% de descuento. */ 
    ], 
    "Mediana": [
        200, .1     /* Para la mediana, costo de 200, 10% de descuento. */
    ],      
    "Grande": [
        300, .2,    /* Para la grande/familiar, costo de 300, 20% de descuento. */
    ]
};

let orden = "Mediana"; /* La pizza que desea el cliente. */
/* Calcularemos el total aplicandole el descuento. */
let total_pagar = pizzas[orden][0] - (pizzas[orden][0] * pizzas[orden][1]);

console.log(`El total a pagar por una pizza ${orden.toLowerCase()} con el ` 
            + `descuento aplicado es de ${total_pagar}.`);
```

El codigo esta mas lineal, sin ramas (los condicionales), pero sin embargo debes tomar en cuenta, cuando la orden no exista en `pizzas` (para que no te de error al querer un miembo que no existe).

### Resultado #1:

```
El total a pagar por una pizza grande con el descuento aplicado es de 240.
```

### #2:

```
El total a pagar por una pizza pequena con el descuento aplicado es de 95.
```

---

En respuesta a:

> Esto es Array, pero muchas gracias. Pero quiero solo condicionales IF, ELSE IF y ELSE ¿si podrías códigos? ¡Porfa! – HaziiProWD94

En primer lugar deberias acostumbrarte a las estructuras de datos. En segundo lugar, dejare el objeto e implementare los condicionales `if`, `if else` y, `else`. No habria que modificar mucho, este seria el codigo:

```
/* Crea un hash con las pizas, y su respectivos costos y descuentos. */
const pizzas = {
    "Pequena": [
        100, .05    /* Para la pequena, costo de 100, 5% de descuento. */ 
    ], 
    "Mediana": [
        200, .1     /* Para la mediana, costo de 200, 10% de descuento. */
    ],      
    "Grande": [
        300, .2    /* Para la grande/familiar, costo de 300, 20% de descuento. */
    ]
};

const orden = "hola"; /* La pizza que desea el cliente. */
/* Calcularemos el total aplicandole el descuento. Usando una lambda or arrow function. */
let total_pagar = (pizzas, orden) => pizzas[orden][0] - (pizzas[orden][0] * pizzas[orden][1]);

/* Verifica que la orden sea valida. Si no lo es, termina la ejecucion. */
if (!(orden in pizzas))
    throw new Error("La orden no se encuentra en el menu!");

if (orden === pizzas[0])
    console.log(`La pizza pequena con el descuento aplicado cuesta ` +
                 `${total_pagar(pizzas, orden)}`);
else if (orden === pizzas[1])
    console.log(`La pizza mediana con el descuento aplicado cuesta ` +
                `${total_pagar(pizzas, orden)}`);
else
    console.log(`La pizza grande/familiar con el descuento aplicado cuesta ` +
                 `${total_pagar(pizzas, orden)}`);
```

### Resultado #1:

**Error case.**

```
/home/djose1164/samples/bar.js:20
    throw new Error("La orden no se encuentra en el menu!");
    ^

Error: La orden no se encuentra en el menu!
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/djose1164/samples/bar.js:20:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

**Working case.**

```
La pizza grande/familiar con el descuento aplicado cuesta 180
```

### Cosas a resltar:

1. Fijate que `total_pagar` es ahora una lambda (arrow function, funcion flecha, etc), por ello lo de los parentesis que usamos en los condiciales.
2. El primer condicional `if (!(orden in pizzas))` nos permitara estar seguro que la orden es valida (ya que si no lo es tirara excep).
3. El codigo incremento bastante al usar los condicionales.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Esta no es mi respuesta... ¿Como calcular precios de pizza con cupon descuento?

Comment: Ok, actualizare la respuesta mostrandote como yo lo haria.

Comment: Esto es Array, pero muchas gracias. Pero quiero solo condicionales IF, ELSE IF y ELSE ¿si podrías códigos? ¡Porfa!

Comment: No, un objecto con un array como miembro. Claro, dame algo de tiempo, actualizare luego.

Comment: Muchas gracias! =D